# Is there a way to broadcast multiple webcams as one image for a video podcast?

Tags: video, webcam, broadcast, podcast

I do an audio podcast and all of the hosts are attached to a computer anyway, so I was wondering if there was a way to have all of our webcams on, and broadcast one image live as we do our show? Does a program/online service exist for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, there's a free utility called CamTwist that allows you to divvy up your video stream between several sources simultaneously - desktop sharing, webcams, images, etc.

For Windows users, I've heard that ManyCam is the closest equivalent to CamTwist.  I haven't used it, but it's worth looking into.